# Stacking/concatenated arrays and "None"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack, concatenation

I have some code:

```
# first round
curr_g = np.array([])
temp_g = np.array([1,2,3])

if curr_g is not None:
    curr_g = temp_g
    print "in is not none"
else:
    curr_g = np.c_[curr_g, temp_g]
    print "in is none"

print "curr_g: "
print curr_g

#second round
temp_g = np.array([4,5,6]) 
if curr_g is not None:
    print "in is not none"
    curr_g = temp_g
else:
    print "in none"
    curr_g = np.c_[curr_g, temp_g]

print "curr_g: "
print curr_g
```

And the output of the above is as follows:

```
in is not none
curr_g: 
[1 2 3]
in is not none
curr_g: 
[4 5 6]
```

Why on earth does the condition go into "Not none" both times around? `curr_g` is only "not None" in the second round, after being assigned `temp_g`.

My objective is that in the first round, because `curr_g` is truly empty, it should be populated with `temp_g`, and the second time, it should actually get concatenated to `temp_g` and become as follows:

```
[
1  4
2  5
3  6
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for `None`, you should assign `None` explicitly.

```
curr_g = None
```

As BrenBarn mentioned, you have assigned an empty `numpy` array, and that is no more equal to `None` than an empty python list is.

Answer (score 2):

"Empty" is not the same as `None`.  `None` is a particular object, and it is different from your (or any) numpy array, so your array is not `None`.

If you want to check whether your array is empty, just do `if curr_g`.  That said, it doesn't make a lot of sense to create an empty array for `curr_g` if all you're going to do is overwrite it with something else.  You could just initialize it with `curr_g = None`, and then your `is None` check will work.